# my code print error even the input is correct

Tags: kotlin

This is origin code

```
if (!isNullOrEmpty(configTypeBuilder.destinationField, RULE_CRITERIA_CONFIG_TYPE_BUILDER_DESTINATION_FIELD_PATH)) {
    if (ruleAttributes.firstOrNull { ruleAttribute -> ruleAttribute == destinationField } == null) {
        addValidationError(RULE_CRITERIA_CONFIG_TYPE_BUILDER_DESTINATION_FIELD_PATH, configTypeBuilder.destinationField, NOT_EXIST_CONSTRAINT)
    }
}
```

I modify the code, just add the invalid value to a list, and then print them, but now when I enter valid destinationField after invalid destinationField, it will still show the error message, I don't know what's going on

```
        val invalidDestination = hashSetOf<String>()

    if (!isNullOrEmpty(configTypeBuilder.destinationField, RULE_CRITERIA_CONFIG_TYPE_BUILDER_DESTINATION_FIELD_PATH)) {
        for (destinationField in destinationFieldList) {
            if (!ruleAttributes.contains(destinationField)) {
                invalidDestination.add(destinationField)
            }
        }
        if (invalidDestination.size > 0) {
            addValidationError(
                "$RULE_CRITERIA_CONFIG_TYPE_BUILDER_DESTINATION_FIELD_PATH $NOT_EXIST_CONSTRAINT",
                DESTINATION,
                "$ADD_TAX_ENGINE_ATTRIBUTE_FIELDS $invalidDestination"
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to show error message only if there are no valid destinations, you need to add one more condition to your if statement. If not please clarify your question and post the whole function

Condition example:

```
    var foundValid = false
    for (destinationField in destinationFieldList) {
        if (!ruleAttributes.contains(destinationField)) {
            invalidDestination.add(destinationField)
        }else {
            foundValid = true
            break //if you need invalidDestination list for later remove this break
        }
    }
    if (invalidDestination.size > 0 && !foundValid) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: can you show me what condition I should add?

Comment: Edited answer see if this helps